# Mapbox tracking mode SDK 4.0.0

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using android Mapbox SDK 4.0.0 and I cann't set center of map when location changed. I don't understand how to use MyLocationTrackingMode. Or how to recive current latitude and longitude and past them to CameraPosition. Can somebody help me, please? Thanks in advance!

```
package com.detores.wristmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.constants.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create a mapView
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                // Set map style
                mapboxMap.setStyleUrl(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);

                // Set the camera's starting position
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(50.0051, 36.3562)) // set the camera's center position
                        .zoom(12)  // set the camera's zoom level
                        .build();

                // Move the camera to that position
                mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understand what you are trying to accomplish then this code snippet might help you get started:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapboxMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener {

private MapboxMap map;
private MapView mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            map = mapboxMap;

            mapboxMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
            mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(@Nullable Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        map.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
    }
}

// Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Glad I could help out. If the answer helped, could you please [mark it correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so others with the same question can quickly locate the answer.